# generating sql trace file from sql developer in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

How can I generate trace file from within SQL developer in Oracle? I know how to generate `explain plan` but I want to know how to generate a trace (`.trc`) file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s several ways you can do it, one is

```
alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12';
```

End it with

```
alter session set events '10046 trace name context off';
```

Then grab the file - you can look up the path by checking the session’s process in `v$process`. If you’re on a modern version of Oracle you can read it directly from `v$diag_trace_file_contents` , Jonathan Lewis has a really useful view that you can set up as SYS to make this simple and safe https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2019/10/03/trace-files-2/

Comment: you can also use the Monitor Sessions page under tools, find your session, right-click, Start/Stop trace